# Android - Box-API just hangs?

Tags: java, android, token, box-api

I've written an application to use the box-api to upload files from a phone.  I authenticate the user via:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, BoxAuthentication.class);
intent.putExtra("API_KEY", Version.BOX_API_KEY);
startActivityForResult(intent, BOX_RESULT);
```

and I get the token returned via:

```
if (resultCode == BoxAuthentication.AUTH_RESULT_SUCCESS)
{
   if(data.getStringExtra("AUTH_TOKEN") != null) {
      writeStringPref(Global.boxToken, data.getStringExtra("AUTH_TOKEN"), getApplicationContext());
   } else { 
      toast("An error occured authenticating, please try again"); finish();
   }
} else if (resultCode == BoxAuthentication.AUTH_RESULT_FAIL) {
   toast("Unable to log into Box"); finish();
}
```

In my upload method I call box via:

```
final Box box = Box.getInstance(Version.BOX_API_KEY);
```

I then create a folder to upload the file to via:

```
box.createFolder(token, 0l, Global.folderName, true, new CreateFolderListener(){
            @Override
            public void onIOException(IOException e) {
                        //HANDLE
            }

            @Override
            public void onComplete(BoxFolder boxFolder, String status) {
               //DO STUFF
                    }
        );
```

The problem I'm having is the first time the user authenticates I can use that saved token to upload files no problem.  But, for example, an hour later when I make the call to create the folder it seems to just hang.  Nothing is returned and neither method in the listener is called.

This also seems to happen when I push an update of the code to the device, it stops working and the only solution is to re-authenticate the user.
Reading the documentation it seems to the token shouldn't expire and as nothing is returned it doesn't seem like it is invalid.

I'm calling this code via an Intent Service if that makes a difference.

Anyone have any ideas what the issue could be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved this myself.. I was calling box from an Intent Service, which isn't on the main thread, therefore when making calls to the box api I was essentially calling a background thread from a background thread.. I have no idea why this worked sometimes and not others but using a handler (main thread) and calling the box-api via that seems to have resolved the issue.